# I want to travel to the US for tourism purpose but I'm a freelancer working for a US company

Tags: visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

What basically I would like to know are my chances of getting a visa. I'm 28 I'd be going for the first time to the US, planning for a week. I've had one tourism-related trip to UAE earlier this year.

I'm worried about proving my socio-economic ties to India. Though I do not wish to settle and will be visiting New York City only for travel, my credentials seem dicey when considered for visa from what I've read so far. I would really like to confirm this though as I'm ready to give it a shot.

So background I'm a freelancer, I've been working full-time as a contractor for a US company for 2 months now. I have enough funds, savings etc, no property to my name, but a family with my mother dependent on me. My father is a retired cop. However, I have nothing concrete in way of employment letter to show. I filled the W8-BEN and would be taking a paid leave from my client.

How do I prove I would be returning on time and have strong ties back home? Do I even stand a chance?

Comment: "Paid leave" and "freelancer" sounds like they don't really belong in the same situation. Will you be billing your client for doing nothing while you're touristing around in the US? It could be difficult to convince authorities that you're then not working.

Comment: Yes I know this is unusual but the client is offering a few benefits and paid leave is one of them. I can either choose to take it or not. Just figured it might build a case for my returning back to home to resume work.